# Tag au sujet des questions qu'on peut ou non poser

Tags: feature-request, tags

Je m'amusais un peu avec les tags du site méta, et je m'aperçois qu'il manque le tag accepted-question, qui existe sur d'autres métas, pour classer les questions relatives à quel genre de question peut être ou non acceptable sur le site principal.

J'en profite pour demander à quoi peut bien correspondre le tag [interesting-tag](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interesting-tag), est-ce qu'il y a des tags qui sont inintéressants?